¿Como podria editar las caracteristicas de v-data-table de vuetify?
¿Como podría editar las características de v-data-table de vuetify? para poder mostrar varios datos en un campo.


 const headers = ref([
    { title: 'Kardex', key: 'actions', sortable: false },
    { title: 'Caso', key: 'caso' },
    { title: 'Tipo', key: 'tipo_bien' },
    { title: 'Jurisdiccion', key: 'jurisdiccion_bien' },
]
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>




Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! la verdad que no se.. pero probaste unir los datos al traerlos??

Hola nerwin, podes utilizar los slots item.{name}, pero sería bueno que des un caso específico, como para poder responder con un ejemplo útil.
